# Cycle through array data and get the longest length for each subarray field

Tags: python

I have a data arrays nestled inside another array.

```
data = [["John", "Portland", "DfIfDdjfkd"], ["Pat", "New York City", "Hdidfhufd"], "Alexander", "Topeka", "dfkjvddf"]]
```

I need to loop through each of these subarrays and record how many characters the longest one is.

```
longestlength = [10, 13, 9]
```

I worked out some loose psudocode, but I'm pretty new to Python so I don't know if I'm even approaching this in the right manner.

```
longestlength = []
for x in data:
    for y in range(len(x[y])):
        if len(x[y]) > longestlength[y]:
            longestlength[y] = len(x[y])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant `[10, 13, 9]`, you can use a *list comprehension* + `max` + `map` + `len`:

```
>>> [max(map(len, x)) for x in data]
[10, 13, 9]
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome!

Comment: Wait, when I put my actual content in it, I realized its just giving me the max length in each row. I'm trying to get the max length in each column. Any idea what tweak I'd need to do?

Comment: @GFL you’ll need to transpose your list. There’s a way to do that using zip. Do search it up!

Comment: Awesome! `[max(map(len, x)) for x in zip(*data)]`